# DataGridView doesn't call Paint method when InvalidateCell is called

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This a WinForm C# application problem.

I have a DataGridView and I need a customized type of DataGridViewColumn such that when my mouse is over a cell on that column, the cell paints something special on it. I found [a way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fb61s43.aspx) of overriding the DataGridViewTextBoxCell to do the painting myself. That article shows an example of implementing a roll-over cell such that when you move your mouse over a cell, it paints a red rectangle around the bounders of itself.

If you see the example, you will find out that the way the example fills data is directly create rows to the grid. When I use data binding rather than direct row fill, I find that the cells will not paint themselves at the beginning. Actually, you have to select a cell first, then all the cells on that row will paint correctly. If you don't select a cell of a row, all the cells on that row will not paint accordingly when the mouse is over them.

I think this is some kind of optimization of the grid such that when you select a cell, the underlying object of that row is activated and the grid will call Paint method when InvlidateCell method is call. But if the underlying object of a row is not activated, the grid will just paint the cells by default method to save time.

Obviously, I need not the optimization but the slow way. It doesn't matter in my case because my data on that grid never get too big. How can I achieve it? I try to call grid.Refresh() after the data is bound to the grid but that doesn't help.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Ji

Comment: If I put this.DataGridView.Refresh() in the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave methods, the problem is fixed. But this causes the whole grid blinks while the mouse is moving on it. I believe it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure I understood your question. Just see if this is somewhat like what you need:

```
bool bSomeFlag = false;
int iCol = 0;
int iRow = 0;
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
            iCol = e.ColumnIndex;
            iRow = e.RowIndex;
            bSomeFlag = true;
            this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
        }
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            if (bSomeFlag && iRow >=0 && iCol>=0) {
                dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What I mean is, if you call InvalidateCell method in the overriden OnMouseEnter event of the customized cell, everytime the InvalidateCell method is called, the Paint method of the cell object should also be called. But this is not true if you use data binding on the grid. For data binding, initially InvalidateCell method will not trigger Paint method. This only happens if you select a cell. Once a cell is selected, all the cells in its row behave normally: InvalidateCell method always fires Paint method.

I already tried your suggestion. It will blink the cell while mouse moving, which is bad

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same issue for a while, the problem is that any method in  `DataGridViewImageButtonCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell` is called with object attribute `RowIndex = -1`, therefore `InvalidateCell()` gets triggered with `rowIndex = -1` so nothing happens.

This is caused by [rows being shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex.aspx):

> When the RowIndex property returns -1, the cell is either a column header, or **the cell's row is shared**.

[MSDN shows some ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx) how you can keep rows shared (thus going against them = unshare row), including:

> For example, a row cannot be shared in any of the following
>   situations:
>
> - The row contains a single selected cell that is not in a selected column.
> - The row contains a cell with its ToolTipText or ContextMenuStrip properties set.
> - **The row contains a DataGridViewComboBoxCell with its Items property set.**
>
> ...
>
> Do not handle the DataGridViewRowCollection.CollectionChanged or **DataGridView.RowStateChanged** events. These events cause rows to become unshared. Also, do not call the DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged or DataGridView.OnRowStateChanged methods, which raise these events.

I've tried using:

```cs
public MyDataGridView()
    : base()
{
    RowStateChanged += MyDataGridView_RowStateChanged;
}

void MyDataGridView_RowStateChanged( object sender,
         DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e )
{
}
```

It worked, but I hated the idea of unsharing rows by default, so I've end up extending my `Cell` class by overloading:

- [`DataGridViewCell.MouseEnterUnsharesRow` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.mouseenterunsharesrow.aspx)
- [`DataGridViewCell.MouseLeaveUnsharesRow` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.mouseleaveunsharesrow.aspx)

So final working code looks like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Required correcting mousve hover displaying
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rowIndex"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected override bool MouseEnterUnsharesRow( int rowIndex )
{
    return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Required correcting mousve hover displaying
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rowIndex"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected override bool MouseLeaveUnsharesRow( int rowIndex )
{
    return true;
}
```